# When will applicationWillTerminate be called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In what situations will applicationWillTerminate be called? For example, will it ocassionally be called if there is a crash in the code?

Apple's doc is vague on this, it only says when the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does applicationWillTerminate work on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460115/how-exactly-does-applicationwillterminate-work-on-iphone)

Answer (score 57):

I have just explored this question (iOS 9.2). And I have got some results.

So, `applicationWillTerminate` is called when a user terminates the app without switching it to background mode: the app is active, the user makes double press on Home button and throws out the app.

But if a user switches the app to the background at first, and then after this tries to terminate the app, `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called.

You can check this:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"term"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"term"]){

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"term"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WORKED" message:@"term works" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
...
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 29):

Starting in iOS 4, the practical answer is "never." (or at least "rarely".) You can't assume that it will ever be called. Normally what happens is that your app gets moved to the background when the user presses the home button and then a few seconds later it shifts to the "suspended state" (Still in memory but not receiving any CPU time.)

Once your app is in the suspended state the system can terminate it at any time without warning (usually due to memory pressure.)

When you are suspended you don't get the applicationWillTerminate call before being killed. You should assume that when you get a `applicationDidEnterBackground:` message, you are going to be suspended shortly after, and die while suspended. Get your affairs in order (save app state.)

You may still get calls to your applicationWillTerminate in certain cases, but you should not assume that you will.

Comment: You can get applicationWillTerminate if you force quit your app right?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try it.

Comment: This answer is correct, but for sake of completeness is better to emphasize the difference between suspended and background. Background is intended when your app has specific backgrounds mode in the info.plist, that makes the app running also after pressing the home button, in all the other case the app goes to a suspended state and this method will never be called (and as far as I know, even when the user kills the app).

Comment: Actually, Apple uses the term background in conflicting ways. The message applicationDidEnterBackground actually means that your application is being "mothballed" (my term, meaning kept in memory, but not longer called at all. This use doesn't really match the computer science definition of background, but it's the way Apple uses it most.) Then there is background processing, which is what you're referring to. Then there's active and inactive.

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground fires when the app goes into background, so is correct usage. The confusion is whether your app *stays* in background or is very shortly suspended. For apps that have background modes enabled, they will remain in background. But for apps without background modes, they will be very shortly suspended.

Comment: on iOS 9.1 using the Sim, the trick is to fire the home shortcut twice from within the app then kill from multitasking. Home then home again twice won't fire.

Answer (score 13):

App Termination according to the [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1):

- Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should not wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks.
- System-initiated termination is a normal part of an app's life cycle.  The system usually terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and make room for other apps being launched by the user, but the system may also terminate apps that are misbehaving or not responding to events in a timely manner.
- Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory.
- If an app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls the **applicationWillTerminate:** of its app delegate prior to termination.
- The system does not call this method when the device reboots.
- In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. 
  User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a suspended app.  The app's process is killed and no notification is sent to the app.

Answer (score 6):

When a user has the app open and then presses the home button iOS doesn't close the app but instead suspends it and puts it in the background.

However, iOS devices only have 1GB of ram (mostly) so after opening and closing a few apps they are starting to run out.

iOS now has to kick some of those apps out of ram. So it wakes up (at a guess the biggest ram user, or oldest used app) an app and tells it to save anything it needs to close down gracefully.

That's when `-applicationWillTerminate:` is called. When iOS is closing down your app. Of course if you block that method from returning for too long iOS will just kill your app anyway (it needs to resources after all).

If you are saving everything in `-willResignActive:` and `-willEnterBackground:` then you can pretty much just ignore the method and your app will close after the method returns.

EDIT: If the user tells the app switcher to close an app it will also try to gracefully close your app down. But if it is a situation where the device needs more resources there's a chance you won't get `-applicationWillTerminate:` called, as the device won't have time to as it might need the resources faster than your app can be told to gracefully close. So `applicationWillTerminate:` isn't guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Force quitting the app that's already backgrounded can also trigger applicationWillTerminate right?

Comment: Yes, it is called when the application is closing (gracefully).

Comment: No, if your app is in the background already, force-quitting it will NOT generate the applicationWillTerminate message.

Comment: To resolve the guess about which app iOS will stop first to free up resources, the [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1) says "Apps with large memory footprints are the first to be terminated by the system"

Comment: this is incorrect... closing apps takes more memory than keeping apps in the background task switcher. Devices have a limited amount of memory sure, but that's why Apple created their new suspend processes to fully stop the app from functioning in the background after a given time (usually a small time)... here is a great link to show this evidence https://daringfireball.net/2017/07/you_should_not_force_quit_apps

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be called when the user kills the app from foreground or when the OS does it himself. the rest of the time it's just a big "maybe". I usually don't rely on that because of that "maybe".

You can use the "didEnterBackground" which is called in a more reliable way

You can also try to create a crash on purpose and see how it reacts exactly (crash from foreground & background).

Answer (score 0):

In swift, use delegate in the below

```
optional func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

ref:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate