# Lifecycle of iOS App During Update

Tags: ios, background-process, lifecycle, ios-lifecycle

I would like to know what state is the app in when an app updates.

For example: 
Lets say we have an app running (called Le Music) that is playing music in background mode.

Now we go to the store and see there is an update available and we tap update.
What is the life cycle on the current version of Le Music during the transition from old version of the app to the new version

Comment: Why don't you test this yourself? Add some logging messages in some of the relevant application delegate methods. Run your app through Xcode. Getting it running as desired. Now do another build through Xcode. Review the relevant log messages from the device console to see what happened.

Comment: Yea, I am doing that regardless. I was hoping someone on the net had a reference article that I can read up on to know what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app will be replaced. That means it will be terminated. You are running in the background *ex hypothesi*, so the only event you *might* hope to get is `applicationWillTerminate`. (However, I wouldn't count on it: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416375/when-will-applicationwillterminate-be-called).) If you were in the background but *not* running, you wouldn't get any event at all.